# Access Denied Error When AssociateVPCWithHostedZone Using Lambda & Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, boto3, amazon-route53

I am trying to create a shared hosted zone between two AWS accounts.

From Account-B I have created a vpc association authorisation with the following, (Lambda-B)

```
response = self.route53.create_vpc_association_authorization(
     HostedZoneId=<Hosted Zone Id>,
     VPC={
            'VPCRegion': <Region>,
            'VPCId': <VPC of Account-A>
         }
)
```

Then from Account-A I tried to accept it. (Lambda-A)

```
                      response = self.route53.associate_vpc_with_hosted_zone(
     HostedZoneId=<Hosted Zone Id>,
     VPC={
            'VPCRegion': <Region>,
            'VPCId': <VPC of Account-A>
         }
)
```

I have attached a role with following policy to Lambda-A

```
  AcceptHostedZoneAssociationRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: AcceptHostedZoneAssociationRolePolicy
      Roles:
      - Ref: AcceptHostedZoneAssociationRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Sid: AssociateDisassociateVPCFromHostedZone
          Action:
          - lambda:*
          - logs:*
          - s3:*
          - iam:PassRole
          - ec2:DescribeVpcs
          - route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone
          - route53:DisassociateVPCFromHostedZone
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: "*"
```

I've got the following error when executing Lambda-A via CF (triggered via a custom resource).

```
[ERROR] 2019-11-15T00:21:30.691Z    b1f7049a-0de7-4324-95ee-817abc12d3bc    Create Vpc Hosted Zone association call Failed An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssociateVPCWithHostedZone operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXX:assumed-role/Default-HostedZone-Accept-AcceptHostedZoneAssociat-128KT4DUCVD0M/HostedZoneAssociationAcceptLambda is not authorized to perform: route53:AssociateVPCWithHostedZone on resource: arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/Z0589797H460WDVIBOBD
```

But if I test the Lambda-A with event data from a failed execution (attaching the same role), it creates the association without a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with my CF script that accept the hosted zone association with the VPC. 
It triggers Lambda function before creating the role policy. 
Fixed after adding "DependsOn" attribute to the custom resource that triggers the Lambda function.

```
LambdaTriggerCustomResource:
DependsOn: AcceptHostedZoneAssociationRolePolicy
Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource'
Version: '1.0'
Properties:
  ServiceToken: !GetAtt HostedZoneAssociationAcceptLambda.Arn
```